# Laravel Request: on default request always return post field required

Tags: laravel, request

Anyone know this issue? Im using laravel 5.2 and this error started showing up today randomly. Whenever there is form with basic Request $request, without any validations it always returns "The post field is required.".

app\Http\Requests\Request.php file is untouched.

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

abstract class Request extends FormRequest
{
    //
}
```

I have no clue what does cause this and how to fix it.

Controller Method

```
public function updateSocial(Request $request)
{
   $this->member->profile()->update([
      'facebook_profile'  =>  $request->facebook_profile,
      'twitter_profile'   =>  $request->twitter_profile,
      'steam_profile'     =>  $request->steam_profile,
   ]);

   return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Information updated');
}
```

Comment: Show us the controller function, which executes when submitting this form.

Comment: Updated, sorry for late updating.

Comment: Fixed it, problem caused one wrong placed route